# CellEditor in EditorGrid loses content when you scroll the grid

Tags: gwt, extjs, gxt

I have an issue where a user enters some data in an EditorGrid cell. Then the user scrolls the grid without clicking anywhere first. Upon scrolling, the edited cell gets reset and the entered data is lost. I recorded this behavior using the GXT editablegrid sample:

recording: http://goo.gl/dqqhK

I am trying to prevent the entered data loss if the users scrolls. I have been experimenting with the CellEditor's onBlur(...) method, which is called when the users scrolls, but it seems that its FieldEvent argument has already lost the entered value. So the completeEdit() just stores nothing.

Is there any way that I can prevent that "data loss" when a user scrolls? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Thomas Amsler
Sakai Project (UC Davis)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me, hope it helps:

```
grid.addListener(Events.OnMouseWheel, new Listener<BaseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handleEvent(BaseEvent be) {
                grid.stopEditing();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. For some reason, the event-listener doesn't receive any Events.OnMouseWheel events. While doing some testing, I replaced the Events.OnMouseWheel with Events.OnMouseMove and it receives those events. Do you have any idea why it wouldn't receive the Events.OnMouseWheel events?

Comment: Interestingly, if I add an "Events.BodyScroll" listener, it seems to work. So I am not sure what the difference is.

Comment: Sounds interesting since both BodyScroll and OnMouseWheel work for me. In the end I have no idea why OnMouseWheel does not work for you. Glad to see you found a solution though.

Comment: @godonline can we somehow prevent losing focus at all?

Comment: @tamsler can we prevent onBlur when scolling ?

Answer (score 0):

Events.BodyScroll works, because when you click up/down arrow of scroll bar or click anywhere of scroll bar is not a MouseWheel event.

I think this should be a GXT bug, hope it will be fixed in the future.